# How to install / test a command line tool you are working on using yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

If you are developing a package that includes a command line tool, then with `npm`, you can:

```
npm install -g # install package in current directory as a global package
```

And then you can start using it from anywhere. Eg, if `package.json` includes

```
"bin": {
    "my_tool": "./index.js"
},
```

then you can `cd` to another directory and run `my_tool` at the terminal. You can even run `npm link` from the package you're developing to symlink the binary to your dev copy so you don't have to `npm install -g` again every time you make changes and want to try them out.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do the same with `yarn`. What's the recommended workflow for installing / testing command line tools you're developing with yarn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yarn global add file:$PWD
```

Source: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5199

Answer (score 0):

> This works on Git Bash for Windows: `yarn global add $PWD`

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5199#issuecomment-581700826